# How to use passed in values as array indices in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing

So I'm trying to learn C++ by creating a basic chess game.
With the added wrinkle that the user can create a non-standard sized board (i.e., not necessarily 8x8)

Once I receive the dimensions of the board from the user though, I should be set to create it at a fixed size.  So I'm thinking to use an array here.

The compiler doesn't like my declaration though:

```
 tile arrayOfTiles[numX][numY];
```

It seems to be telling me it wants a constant as the array indices.
Is this something I can even do with an array?

```
class gameBoard{
    public:
    gameBoard(int x=8, int y=8)
    :   numX(x),
        numY(y)
{
    //construct board
    tile arrayOfTiles[numX][numY];

    /*
    for (int i=0; i<numX; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<numY; j++){
            arrayOfTiles[i][j]=tile();
            }
        }
    */
}

protected:
    int numX;  //total number of rows, typically 8 (A-H) on a chessboard
    int numY;  //total number of columns, typically 8 (1-8) on a chessboard

};
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<tile>> arrayOfTiles(numX, std::vector<tile>(numY));
```

Use `typedef` to simplify it:

```
typedef std::vector<tile>  vectiles;

std::vector<vectiles> arrayOfTiles(numX, vectiles(numY));
```

`vectiles` is a vector of tile, and `arrayOfTiles` is a vector of `vectiles`. You can treat as if it is 2D array.

```
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < numX; ++i)
{
     for(size_t j = 0 ; j < numY; ++j)
         //use arrayOfTiles[i][j]
}
```

Instead of `numX` and `numY`, you can use `arrayOfTiles.size()` and `arrayOfTiles[i].size()` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The best that you can do here is let the `gameBoard` internally hold `arrayOfTiles` as one of its data members, and instead of C-style arrays you should rather use `std::vector` instead:

```
protected:
    std::vector< std::vector<tile> > arrayOfTiles;
```

Then you can initialize it in your initialization list:

```
public:
    gameBoard(int x = 8, int y = 8)
    : numX(x), numY(y), arrayOfTiles(x, std::vector<tile>(y));
    {
        // ...
    }
```